# Pass Member Function To glfwSet*Callback

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm trying to setup an 'event receiver' class to wrap the GLFW callbacks into a class users can inherit from but having an issue passing the base-class member function into the GLFW 'set callback' functions.

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

//
//
//  Event Receiver Framework

enum EventTypes {
    Keyboard = 1,
    Mouse = 2
};

struct Event {
    EventTypes Action;
    //  Other Event Related Values
};

class EventReceiver {
    void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
        Event NewEvent;
        NewEvent.Action = EventTypes::Keyboard;
        OnEvent(NewEvent);
    }

public:
    virtual void OnEvent(Event& NewEvent) = 0;
};

//
//
//  Application Framework

class MyApplication {
    GLFWwindow* window;
public:
    void SetEventReceiver(EventReceiver* EventHandler) {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, &EventHandler->key_callback);
    }

};

//
//  
//  User-Defined Event Receiver

class MyEventReceiver : public EventReceiver {
public:
    void OnEvent(Event& NewEvent) {
        if (NewEvent.Action == EventTypes::Keyboard) {
            //  Custom Event Actions
        }
        else if (NewEvent.Action == EventTypes::Mouse) {
            //  Custom Event Actions
        }
    }
};

//
//
//  Main

int main() {
    MyEventReceiver _Events;
    MyApplication _App;
    _App.SetEventReceiver(&_Events);
    //
    //  Do logic
    //
    return 0;
}
```

This essentially provides a base-class with pure virtual functions for users to inherit from and override to provide their own logic for when events happen. The user-defined sub-class is meant to be passed into a larger 'application-framework' class which makes the necessary calls to setup the GLFW callback functions.

Of course you cannot pass a member function as a function argument expecting a c-style-function because you must provide access to the class instance, or in other words, you have to provide the class instance so the member function being called knows what object to use as the 'this pointer'.

I am not sure how to do this exactly in regards to the 'glfwSet*Callback' functions inside GLFW.

Comment: You can try creating a static function and passing an instance of "this" as a void* data or some context argument. You can also try using std::bind that could possibly work.

Comment: I've attempted to use std::bind but the compiler gives an error about not being able to pass the output of std::bind to the glfw set callback function

Comment: Then static member functions is your best bet. Essentially it doesn't even have to be a member of the class as long as you retain the instance pointer in the callback. I'm sure glfwset allows you to pass some void*/context argument.

Comment: Unfortunately GLFW does not allow the use of member functions here, static is the only way to go so it would seem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only static member functions can be used like this in GLFW, instead, you can use glfwGetWindowUserPointer and glfwSetWindowUserPointer to provide access to the underlying class object in these situations if you require it.

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

//
//
//  Event Receiver Framework

enum EventTypes {
    Keyboard = 1,
    Mouse = 2
};

struct Event {
    EventTypes Action;
    //  Other Event Related Values
};


class EventReceiver {
    static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
        Event NewEvent;
        NewEvent.Action = EventTypes::Keyboard;
        static_cast<EventReceiver*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window))->OnEvent(NewEvent);
    }

public:
    virtual void OnEvent(Event& NewEvent) = 0;
    friend class MyApplication;
};

//
//
//  Application Framework

class MyApplication {
    GLFWwindow* window;
public:
    void SetEventReceiver(EventReceiver* EventHandler) {
        glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, EventHandler);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, &EventReceiver::key_callback);
    }

};

//
//  
//  User-Defined Event Receiver

class MyEventReceiver : public EventReceiver {
public:
    void OnEvent(Event& NewEvent) {
        if (NewEvent.Action == EventTypes::Keyboard) {
            //  Custom Event Actions
        }
        else if (NewEvent.Action == EventTypes::Mouse) {
            //  Custom Event Actions
        }
    }
};

//
//
//  Main

int main() {
    MyEventReceiver _Events;
    MyApplication _App;
    _App.SetEventReceiver(&_Events);
    //
    //  Do logic
    //
    return 0;
}
```